# Installing Infer Using Brew Failed (No Bottle)

Tags: homebrew, facebook-infer

I am trying to install Infer, a static analysis tool developed by Facebook. I tried following the tutorial for Mac at this link: https://fbinfer.com/docs/getting-started/. I used the "brew install infer" command, however, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: infer: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
brew install --build-from-source infer
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I just followed the instruction. Please help! Thank you

Comment: What is your macOS version? Check the list of versions from infer's homebrew page if there's a bottle for your macOS version: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/infer

Comment: 11.4 is the version

Comment: Is it the new M1 mac? Because the Homebrew page only shows bottles for Intel.

Comment: I believe so, it says "MacBook Air (M1, 2020)"

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my [modified brew formula](https://gist.github.com/T1T4N/2c93997d50157c0fab580f13ac3c7048) to install it on macOS 12 + Apple Silicon.
It works using commit [5fd2f95](https://github.com/facebook/infer/commit/5fd2f95ff63ca0081509864b21e05ad8729f1f3b) (HEAD) and not v1.1.0.